# Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then $-1$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if $ p = 1\mod 4.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then $-1$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if $ p = 1\mod 4.$

**Proof.** For any $x\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ call the following the bundle generated by $x$:
$$ B(x) = \{ x, x^{-1}, -x, -x^{-1} \}. $$

Check $B(x) = B(x^{-1}) = B(-x) = B(-x^{-1}) .$ The distinct bundles partition $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\} .$ Since $p\neq 2$, $x\neq -x$ for all non-zero $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p,$ every package has $4$ elements unless $x= x^{-1} $ or $x=-x^{-1}.$ If $x=x^{-1}$ then $x=\pm 1$ and $B(x) =\{1,-1\}$ has $2$ elements. $x=-x^{-1}$ if and only if $x^2=-1$ and if so, $B(x) = B(-x) = \{x,-x\} $ has two elements.

If $-1$ is a square then $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\} $ is partitioned into $2$ sets of size $2$ and the rest of size $4.$ In that case, $p-1 = 0 \mod 4.$ If $-1$ is not a square then $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\} $ is partitioned into a set with size $2$ and the rest with size $4$, i.e $p-1=2 \mod 4.$

**Can you check this answer? Thanks...**

**#StayAtHome**

Comment: very creative, looks good to me